# Convert dictionary into list with length based on values

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a dictionary

```
d = {1: 3, 5: 6, 10: 2}
```

I want to convert it to a list that holds the keys of the dictionary. Each key should be repeated as many times as its associated value.

I've written this code that does the job:

```
d = {1: 3, 5: 6, 10: 2}
l = []
for i in d:
    for j in range(d[i]):
        l.append(i)
l.sort()
print(l)
```

Output:

```
[1, 1, 1, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 10, 10]
```

But I would like it to be a list comprehension. How can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using a list comprehension:

```
[i for i in d for j in range(d[i])]
```

yields:

```
[1, 1, 1, 10, 10, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5]
```

You can sort it again to get the list you were looking for.

Comment: Or you could sort `d` before doing the list comprehension. For large dictionaries this would be faster, since the dictionary has fewer items than the resulting list. In other words, `[i for i in sorted(d) for j in range(d[i])]`.

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to use [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) to glue sublists together

```
>>> list(itertools.chain(*[[k]*v for k, v in d.items()]))
[1, 1, 1, 10, 10, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5]
```

Or if you are dealing with a very large dictionary, then you could avoid constructing the sub lists with [`itertools.chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) and [`itertools.repeat`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/itertools.html#itertools.repeat)

```
>>> list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(itertools.repeat(k, v) for k, v in d.items()))
[1, 1, 1, 10, 10, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5]
```

Comparative timings for a very large dictionary with using a list comprehension that uses two loops:

```
>>> d = {i: i for i in range(100)}
>>> %timeit list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(itertools.repeat(k, v) for k, v in d.items()))
10000 loops, best of 3: 55.6 µs per loop
>>> %timeit [k for k, v in d.items() for _ in range(v)]
10000 loops, best of 3: 119 µs per loop
```

It's not clear whether you want your output sorted (your example code does not sort it), but if so simply presort `d.items()`

```
# same as previous examples, but we sort d.items()
list(itertools.chain(*[[k]*v for k, v in sorted(d.items())]))
```

Answer (score 1):

`[k for k,v in d.items() for _ in range(v)]`
... I guess...

if you want it sorted you can do

`[k for k,v in sorted(d.items()) for _ in range(v)]`

Answer (score 1):

[`Counter.elements()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.elements) method does exactly this:

```
from collections import Counter

d = {1: 3, 5: 6, 10: 2}
c = Counter(d)
result = list(c.elements())
print(result)
# [1, 1, 1, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 10, 10]
```