# Iterate through Python dictionary and special append to new list?

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, append, key-value

I would like to iterate over a dictionary, and append each key (letter) repeated by the number of times of its value (frequency) to a new list.

For example: 
input: `{'A':1, 'B':2}`. Expected output: `['A', 'B', 'B']`

What I'm doing is not working. What do I write in my function to do this?

```
def get_freq_dict():
    freq_dict = {'J' : 1, 'K' : 1, 'Q' : 1, 'X' : 1, 'Z' : 1,\
                'B' : 2, 'C' : 2, 'F' : 2, 'H' : 2, 'M' : 2, 'P' : 2,\
                'V' : 2, 'W' : 2, 'Y' : 2, '' : 2,\
                'G' : 3, 'D' : 4, 'L' : 4, 'S' : 4, 'U' : 4,\
                'N' : 6, 'R' : 6, 'T' : 6, 'O' : 8, 'A' : 9, 'I' : 9,\
                'E' : 12}
    return freq_dict


def bag_of_letters(freq_dict):
    freq_lst = [] 
    for key, value in freq_dict.items():
        for range in(value):
            freq_lst.append(value)
    return freq_lst


def main():

    freq_dict = get_freq_dict()
    freq_lst = bag_of_letters(freq_dict)

    print(freq_dict, freq_lst)
main()
```

Comment: `for range in(value):` seems suspicious, maybe rethink that line.

Comment: Please also add in your question what exactly is not working. Do you get an exception? What is your result?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert dictionary into list with length based on values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39987708/convert-dictionary-into-list-with-length-based-on-values)

Answer (score 4):

**The culprit**:

```
for range in(value):
    freq_lst.append(value)
```

**The rescuer**:

```
for i in range(value):
     freq_lst.append(key)
```

**Hence**:

```
def get_freq_dict():
    freq_dict = {'J' : 1, 'K' : 1, 'Q' : 1, 'X' : 1, 'Z' : 1,\
                'B' : 2, 'C' : 2, 'F' : 2, 'H' : 2, 'M' : 2, 'P' : 2,\
                'V' : 2, 'W' : 2, 'Y' : 2, '' : 2,\
                'G' : 3, 'D' : 4, 'L' : 4, 'S' : 4, 'U' : 4,\
                'N' : 6, 'R' : 6, 'T' : 6, 'O' : 8, 'A' : 9, 'I' : 9,\
                'E' : 12}
    return freq_dict


def bag_of_letters(freq_dict):
    freq_lst = []
    for key, value in freq_dict.items():
       # print(key, value)
        for i in range(value):
            freq_lst.append(key)
    return freq_lst


def main():

    freq_dict = get_freq_dict()
    freq_lst = bag_of_letters(freq_dict)

    print(freq_lst)
main()
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
['J', 'K', 'Q', 'X', 'Z', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'F', 'F', 'H', 'H', 'M', 'M', 'P', 'P', 'V', 'V', 'W', 'W', 'Y', 'Y', '', '', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'L', 'L', 'L', 'L', 'S', 'S', 'S', 'S', 'U', 'U', 'U', 'U', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'R', 'R', 'R', 'R', 'R', 'R', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'I', 'I', 'I', 'I', 'I', 'I', 'I', 'I', 'I', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E']
```

**OR**

if you want them **nicely paired**:

```
 for i in range(value):
     freq_lst.append([key]*value)
```

**OP**: *However I'm still having trouble with the printed output. It gives me what I'm looking for but also the original dictionary on top*

**Ans**: Because you're printing both the `dict` and the `list`:

```
print(freq_dict, freq_lst)
```

Just print the `list` instead:

```
print(freq_lst)
```

**EDIT 2:**

Another nicer way of grouping the similar elements together, using `groupby()`:

Append the `key` only:

```
 for i in range(0, value):
      freq_lst.append(key)
```

and then:

```
 print([list(j) for i, j in groupby(freq_lst)])
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
[['J'], ['K'], ['Q'], ['X'], ['Z'], ['B', 'B'], ['C', 'C'], ['F', 'F'], ['H', 'H'], ['M', 'M'], 
 ['P', 'P'], ['V', 'V'], ['W', 'W'], ['Y', 'Y'], ['', ''], ['G', 'G', 'G'], 
 ['D', 'D', 'D', 'D'], ['L', 'L', 'L', 'L'], ['S', 'S', 'S', 'S'], ['U', 'U', 'U', 'U'], 
 ['N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N'], ['R', 'R', 'R', 'R', 'R', 'R'], 
 ['T', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'T'], ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O'], 
 ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A'], 
 ['I', 'I', 'I', 'I', 'I', 'I', 'I', 'I', 'I'], 
 ['E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E']]
```

Answer (score 0):

You should iterate through a `range` instead, and append `key` rather than `value`:

```
for key, value in freq_dict.items():
    for _ in range(value):
        freq_lst.append(key)
```

Alternatively, you can use a list comprehension:

```
def bag_of_letters(freq_dict):
    return [i for k, v in freq_dict.items() for i in [k] * v]
```

Comment: `freq_lst.extend([key]*value)` ?

Comment: Thank you that makes more sense. However I'm still having trouble with the printed output. It gives me what I'm looking for but also the original dictionary on top. ex - {'J': 1, 'K': 1, 'Q': 1,'....  ['J', 'K', 'Q', …..]} where all i'm looking for is ['J', 'K', 'Q', …..]}

Comment: @Tim You can `print(freq_lst)` instead of `print(freq_dict, freq_lst)`.

Answer (score 0):

Here you are

```
freq_dict = {'J' : 1, 'K' : 1, 'Q' : 1, 'X' : 1, 'Z' : 1,\
            'B' : 2, 'C' : 2, 'F' : 2, 'H' : 2, 'M' : 2, 'P' : 2,\
            'V' : 2, 'W' : 2, 'Y' : 2, '' : 2,\
            'G' : 3, 'D' : 4, 'L' : 4, 'S' : 4, 'U' : 4,\
            'N' : 6, 'R' : 6, 'T' : 6, 'O' : 8, 'A' : 9, 'I' : 9,\
            'E' : 12}


def bag_of_letters():
    freq_lst = []

    for key in freq_dict:
        for i in range(0, freq_dict[key]):
            freq_lst.append(key)

    return freq_lst


def main():
    freq_lst = bag_of_letters()
    print(freq_lst)


main()
```

---

result ['J', 'K', 'Q', 'X', 'Z', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'F', 'F', 'H', 'H', 'M', 'M', 'P', 'P', 'V', 'V', 'W', 'W', ecc]

Answer (score 0):

You could harness fact that

*If items(), keys(), values(), iteritems(), iterkeys(), and itervalues() are called with no intervening modifications to the dictionary, the lists will directly correspond.*

as shown in [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/835092/python-dictionary-are-keys-and-values-always-the-same-order), therefore you might just do:

```
import itertools
x = {'A':1, 'B':2}
out = list(map(lambda x,y: [x]*y, x.keys(), x.values()))
print(out) #[['A'], ['B', 'B']]
out = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(out))
print(out) #['A', 'B', 'B']
```

I used `itertools` to flatten list, if you do not wish to `import itertools` you might do:

```
out = sum(out,[])
```

instead of

```
out = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(out))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do it with `Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter

d = {'C': 3, 'B': 2, 'A': 1}
c = Counter(d)
list(c.elements())
# ['C', 'C', 'C', 'B', 'B', 'A']
```