# Dictionary to List where the key is repeated the number of times of the value

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I need to convert a Dictionary to a List where the key is repeated the number of times of the value.

```
dict = {'foo':3, 'bar':1}
```

expect result:

```
['foo', 'foo', 'foo', 'bar']
```

Comment: Also: [Iterate through Python dictionary and special append to new list?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54802168/7851470)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `collections.Counter`:

```
>>> [*Counter(dict).elements()]
['foo', 'foo', 'foo', 'bar']
```

A little benchmark comparing this with a supposedly faster solution (and a third solution, doing [what `Counter` does](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/b5789a7419655f66692fab463320048bd2290e81/Lib/collections/__init__.py#L572-L592), but directly to the dict). Numbers are times, so lower=faster:

```
0.31 Counter
0.70 listcomp
0.27 itertools

0.32 Counter
0.72 listcomp
0.28 itertools

0.32 Counter
0.72 listcomp
0.29 itertools
```

Benchmark code:

```
import timeit
from collections import Counter
from itertools import chain, starmap, repeat

data = {i: i % 10 + 1 for i in range(1000)}

solutions = {
    'Counter':   lambda: [*Counter(data).elements()],
    'listcomp':  lambda: [v for v, c in data.items() for _ in range(c)],
    'itertools': lambda: list(chain.from_iterable(starmap(repeat, data.items())))
    }

for _ in range(3):
    for name, solution in solutions.items():
        t = min(timeit.repeat(solution, number=1000))
        print('%.2f' % t, name)
    print()
```

Comment: @superbrain Holy sh*t, that doesn't make sense to me! Calling 3 methods, unpacking, casting to list is faster than a plain list comprehension? How come?! Time complexity should be somewhat similar, as a nested loop flattens to the same number of iterations as the number of elements in the result.

Comment: @VisioN I guess it's because of C speed vs Python speed. The list comprehension runs some Python for every element.

Comment: @superbrain But list comprehension is also implemented in C. Maybe the slowness comes from the range object? Anyways, I have to remove my initial comment, as it seems to be totally wrong. Good catch!

Comment: @VisioN Well, the list comprehension "itself" is implemented in C. But it's evaluating your Python expressions all the time.

Comment: `[item for k,v in data.items() for item in [k]*v]` doesn't call `range()` and it will be about 25% faster than the former listcomp. Still slower than the other two solutions.

Answer (score 2):

Use a list comprehension to create a sub lists of required length and then flatten it:

```
list(chain.from_iterable([[k] * v for k, v in dict.items()]))
```

**Example**:

```
from itertools import chain

dict = {'foo':3, 'bar':1}

print(list(chain.from_iterable([[k] * v for k, v in dict.items()])))
# ['foo', 'foo', 'foo', 'bar']
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use simple list comprehension to complete the job.

```
mylist = [key for key, value in mydict.items() for _ in range(value)]
```

**Output:**

```
['foo', 'foo', 'foo', 'bar']
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
dict = {'foo':3, 'bar':1}
my_list = []
for key, value in dict.items():
    for _ in range(value):
        my_list.append(key)
```

Output:

```
['foo', 'foo', 'foo', 'bar']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    result = []
    dict = {'foo': 3, 'bar': 1}
    for key in dict.keys():
        key_value = dict[key]
        for i in range(key_value):
            result.append(key)
    print(result)
```

or you could do:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    result = []
    dict = {'foo': 3, 'bar': 1}
    result = [k for k, v in dict.items() for _ in range(v)]
    print(result)
```

Both Outputs are:

```
['foo', 'foo', 'foo', 'bar']
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple way using plain list comprehension coupled with list multiplication.

```
d = {'foo':3, 'bar':1}
l = [item for k,v in d.items() for item in [k]*v]
print(l)

['foo', 'foo', 'foo', 'bar']
```